# Excel Run-time error '6': Overflow with the Variant

Tags: excel, vba, integer-overflow

I have been trying to run this code, I got this on the internet and think maybe I can use this on my worksheet. Here is the code and I am getting "Overflow issues"

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ar As Variant
Dim j As Integer
Dim str As String

ar = Sheet3.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    For j = 2 To UBound(ar)
        If InStr(str & ",", "," & ar(j, 1) & ",") = 0 Then str = str & "," & ar(j, 1)
    Next

    Sheet1.ComboBox1.List = Split(Mid(str, 2), ",")
    Sheet1.ComboBox2.Clear
    Sheet1.ComboBox3.Clear

End Sub
```

Sheet3 has 4 columns with 43k rows. Maybe that's where I am getting the error. I try to cut-off my data to 35k and it works perfectly, however, regions are not complete.

What should I do with this? Thank you in advance Guys!

***EDIT***
My problem was fixed thanks to BraX for helping me, J should be Long and not an Integer.

Now, another problem has occur with the other part of the codes. Here it is.

```
Function Cmbo(j)
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ar As Variant
Dim str As String

ar = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    *For i = 1 To UBound(ar)*
        For n = 1 To j
            If ar(i, n) <> Sheet1.OLEObjects("ComboBox" & n).Object.Value Then Exit For
        Next n
        If n = j + 1 And InStr(str & ",", "," & ar(i, n) & ",") = 0 Then
            str = str & "," & ar(i, n)
        End If
    Next

Cmbo = Mid(str, 2)
End Function
```

The error shows type mismatch, error 13. Thanks guys!

Comment: Don't use `Integer` for `j` - Integers in VBA have a limit of 32,767 - Use a `Long` instead.

Comment: Hi BraX, it works! Thanks! However, I encounter another error, error 13, says type mismatch. Here's the code `Function Cmbo(j)
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ar As Variant
Dim str As String

ar = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    For i = 1 To UBound(ar)
        For n = 1 To j
            If ar(i, n) <> Sheet1.OLEObjects("ComboBox" & n).Object.Value Then Exit For
        Next n
        If n = j + 1 And InStr(str & ",", "," & ar(i, n) & ",") = 0 Then
            str = str & "," & ar(i, n)
        End If
    Next

Cmbo = Mid(str, 2)
End Function`

Comment: Where is your type mismatch?

Comment: you should change `Function Cmbo(j)` to `Function Cmbo(j As Integer)`. BTW you'd better get in the habit of dimming `... To Long` instead of `... To Integer`, to avoid possible overfow errors since `Integer`s span between some +/-32k while `Long`s span to some +/-2 billions...

Comment: and please do not post a bunch of code into a comment. as you can see they do not format correctly. instead, add more information to your question after the original question, but even then, you want to try and limit your questions to one per post, as they are intended to help other people too later, and not just you this one time.